# parent wont scale with the child content

Tags: html, css, position

I have a problem that I believe is an easy fix, but I really dont know how.

If you look at the picture, I want to exclude the "white" and let the outer border, and blue background be (I assume) relative to the content (movies + inner black border for movies). My class "BoxModel" is the box that contains the movies, and its size is dependant on the movies. I simply want the outer border (in this case the class border) to also move accordingly to the "BoxModel"'s size, but clearly it (the height) stays up there, while the BoxModel moves from the movies.
[image]

OBS: I have marked the picture so it is clear what class is what. If you want the css, I can provide it. 
**Below is HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>Emilz kys recensions sida 1.0 </title>
    <link href="CSS/Recension.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script> 
    <script src="JS/imdb.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Navbar.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>

   <div class="border">
      <div class='nav'>
         <ul>
            <!-- Hem -->
            <li><a href='Hem.html'>Hem</a></li>
            <!-- Filmer -->
            <li>
               <a href='Filmer.html'>Filmer</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='FilmRecension.html'>Recension</a></li>
                  <li><a href='FilmSlumpad.html'>Slumpa Film</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Serier -->
            <li>
               <a href='Serier.html'>Serier</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='SerieRecension.html'>Recension</a></li>
                  <li><a href='SerieSlumpad.html'>Slumpa Serie</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Om oss -->
            <li><a href='Om oss.html'>Om oss</a></li>
            <li class='lamp'><span></span></li>
         </ul>
        <h1 class="Logo">Recension Sidan<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span></h1>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="BoxModel">
             <!-- Början på filmgalleriet -->

                    <!-- Family Guy -->
                    <section>
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie001" title="movie-001"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGRkMTllZTUtZTQyYi00NjVlLTlhZjEtODExNjQ4YjQ1Y2RjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA4NzY1MzY@._V1_UY268_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Family Guy</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Game of Thrones -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie002" title="movie-002"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEwOTcxODc2Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjMyMDk2MTI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Game of Thrones</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie003" title="movie-003"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie004" title="movie-004"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie005" title="movie-005"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie006" title="movie-006"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie007" title="movie-007"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie008" title="movie-008"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie009" title="movie-009"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie010" title="movie-010"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <!-- Slumdog Millionaire -->
                    <figure>
                    <a href="FilmInfo.html" alt="movie011" title="movie-011"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU2NTA5NzI0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjUxMjYxMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"></a>
                    <figcaption>Slumdog Millionaire</figcaption>
                    </figure>                   
                    </section>

               <!-- Slutet på filmgalleriet -->
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Below is CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);

h1{
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
     text-align:center; 
     font-size:40px;
     color: white;  
     font-weight: bold;
} 
.MovieThumbnail{
    width: 70%;
    height:70%;
}
.Logo{

    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top:22px;
    font-size: 2vw;
    }
.border{
    background-color: #222;  
    border-left: 20px solid rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.5);
    border-right: 20px solid rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.5);
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    /* border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px; */

}
.BoxModel{
    background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.5);
    border: 10px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 25px;

}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.TextContent{
    color: #CBCBCB;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size:110%;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.white{
    color:white; /* Möjligtvis rätt onödig.. */
}
.searchButton{

    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #178086; /* Orange- & Brown ish  #178086 */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 9px 24px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center; /* texten är align center utan denna kodrad.... */
    border-radius: 6px;
    /* border: 2px solid #222; */ /* Lägger en ram på knappen, ser sådär ut xD */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none; /* Tar bort den blåa ramen när man klickar på en knapp. */
}
.searchButton:hover{
    background-color:#178086;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.searchButton:after {
    content: "";
    background: #f1f1f1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300%;
    padding-left: 350%;
    margin-left: -20px !important;
    margin-top: -120%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s
}
.searchButton:active:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s
}
.movieInput{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
}
.movieInput:focus {
    border: 3px solid #555;
}
.nav a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.nav{
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background:#222;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* border-bottom: 5px solid #178086; */
}
.btn btn-primary btn-block{
    color: red;
}
.nav>ul{
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.nav>ul>li>ul{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
}
.nav>ul>li:hover>ul li a{
  opacity:1;
  height:50px;
   transition:all .3s linear;
  -o-transition:all .3s linear;
  -moz-transition:all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s linear;
}
.nav>ul>li>ul a{
  display:block;
  color:#222;
  width:150px;
  line-height:50px !important;
  font:700 14px 'pt sans',sans-serif;
  background:#eee;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0 5px;
   height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  opacity:0;
    transition:all .3s linear .2s;
  -o-transition:all .3s linear .2s;
  -moz-transition:all .3s linear .2s;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s linear .2s;
}
.nav>ul>li{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.nav>ul>li>a{
  padding:0 20px;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  line-height:70px !important;
  font:400 15px 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.lamp span{
  display:block;
  height:4px;
  background: #178086;   /*#ee6666;*/
  position: relative;
}
.lamp span:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(238, 102, 102, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #178086;
    border-width: 4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
.lamp{
  position:absolute !important;
  height:4px;
  top:66px;
  background:#333;
  transition:all .3s linear;
  -o-transition:all .3s linear;
  -moz-transition:all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s linear;
}
.selected.active>a,.active>a{
  transition:all .3s linear;
  -o-transition:all .3s linear;
  -moz-transition:all .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s linear;
  color:#fff;
}
.credit{
  text-align:center;
  margin:20px 0;
}
.blog-link{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
background:#eee;
background-size:40px;
line-height:50px;
display:inline-block;
padding:0 10px;
border-radius:4px;
border-bottom:3px solid #ddd;
color:#333;
font-family:'open sans',sans-serif;
margin:10px;
}
.dgithub{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
background:#eee url('https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-MOW-T0KLZJI/UyR6EIggYkI/AAAAAAAAEbM/el92Uoxz-aI/s50-no/GitHub-Mark.png') no-repeat;
background-size:40px;
line-height:50px;
display:inline-block;
padding:0 10px 0 50px;
background-position:5px;
border-radius:4px;
border-bottom:3px solid #ddd;
color:#333;
font-family:'open sans',sans-serif;
margin:10px;
}
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}
@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}
#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
/*------------------------------Start FilmerOchSerier.html CSS------------------------------*/
body,html,h1,h2,p, div,a,img,header,footer,span,section,nav,aside,article,figure,figcaption{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{ 
    height:100%;
    font-size: 15px;
}
body{
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-image:url(../Bilder/BackgroundBlurred.jpg); // BAKGRUNDSBILD TILL HELA HEMSIDAN
    width:100%; /* kan förstöra mkt xD */
    /* height:100%; xd */
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
section{
    width:100%; /* gör ingen skillnad för tillfället */
    /*  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #ccc; */ /*Detta är en vit "shadow" som visar ramen på section elementet. */
    padding: 1rem 0;
}  /*  #178086 blååe*/
figure{
    width: calc(80% / 4);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
section::after,section::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
section::after{
    clear: both;
}
figure a{
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
figure img{
    width: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    /* Border till filmthumbnail */
    border-left: solid 5px #178086;
    border-right: solid 5px #178086;
    border-top: solid 5px #178086;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}
figcaption{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: #178086;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .7rem;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
}
/* Hanterar fontstorleken samt antal filmer per rad, beroende på hemsidans bredd */
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px){
    html{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    figure{
        width: calc(100% /3);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:840px){
    html{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    figure{
        width: calc(100% /3);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
    html{
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    figure{
        width: calc(100% /2);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:400px){
    html{font-size: 10.5px;}
    figure{
        width:100%;
   }

}
/*------------------------------Slut FilmerOchSerier.html CSS------------------------------*/

/*------------------------------Start FilmInfo.html CSS------------------------------*/
.moviePoster{
    width: calc(100% /3.5);  
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    /* Border till filmthumbnail */
    border-left: solid 3px #178086; 
    border-right: solid 3px #178086; 
    border-top: solid 3px #178086; 
    border-bottom: solid 3px #178086; /* Orange/brown: #178086; Darkgrey: */
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/*------------------------------Slut FilmInfo.html CSS------------------------------*/

/*------------------------------Start Om oss.html CSS------------------------------*/
.OmOssBild{
    max-width: 670px; /*Ramen kan aldrig bli större än bilden*/ 
    max-height: 409px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../Bilder/DumDummare1.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    border: 2px solid #178086;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
/*------------------------------Slut Om oss.html CSS------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because you didn't show us your CSS, but it's probably an issue related to floated items.

When you have floated items, you should use clear right after them, so  it can controls the behavior of floating elements.

So, in your case, please try putting a class `clear` right before you close `BoxModel`, where `.clear` is:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt change anything, but i will add the css on to the post.

Comment: You put `<div class="clear"></div>` exactly where is the comment `<!-- Slutet på filmgalleriet -->`, before close `BoxModel`?

Comment: Yep i did. But i think the problem has to do with parent,child and position related stuff. I have float in css for the movies though.

Comment: The issue is the class `border` has `height: 100%`. Just remove it or replace by `height: auto`

Comment: Damn that fixed all of it! of course the blue part stayed up there but i just added "auto" to html, and body css and it all worked out. Thx!